# Arduino controlled LM350 low output voltage

Tags: arduino, linear-regulator

I'm trying to build smart battery charger with arduino at its core. I need to somehow regulate flowing current and to do this I decided to use linear regulator LM350 and MOSFETN IRF540N. The problem in which I run into is that LM350 doesn't output voltage which I expect. If I supply 10V on adjust pin and 12V on input pin, shouldn't output be somewhere in the range of 10-11.25V? What I'm currently getting is only 7V.

Here is a simple diagram of what I'm trying to do.
[image]

Comment: Make sure to follow the recommendations in the datasheet of the LM350 on input and output capacitors

Comment: You are very marginal on dropout voltage. The LM350 is specified with a 3V minimum difference between input and output voltages; typical (but not guaranteed) curves for dropout voltage against temperature and current are on the datasheet. Why do you need such a high output voltage? What is "smart" about this circuit? (You need feedback if it is to be smart).

Comment: I monitor current and voltage using voltage dividers but I didn't included them here to keep it more simple. What I should point out that if current flowing through circuit is low, for example when transistor is off, output voltage is correct. When current increases tho, (around 1A) voltage output drops.